# Visual Studio Remote Debugging not working with this environment?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, pdb-files

My Development server is managed by an enterprise team.
The application is run with a Windows Service account (XYZ)

My Windows account is ABC.
I am able to connect to the server with Visual Studio and the PDB file is present.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio to manually load this file during my debug session?

I've clicked "Tools" then Options then Symbols and added the network path to the development server (\servername\applicationname) and then I clicked "Load all symbols"

[image: Full Debugging]

Comment: Can you attach the debugger to the remote process?

Comment: I can attach to the process but symbols won't load so I can' debug the code or see why it's failing